# How do I download the language packs for Squiggly?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, squiggly

I'm using Squiggly to add dynamic spell checking library code to the project and I need to add a new language. Where do I download new language packages that I might tie into the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
A simpler solution is mentioned at the end.

**Original Answer:**

This is a complimentary answer to the one by @gabriel. Here is how I was able to get the dictionaries. I found links to a few sites that have dictionaries on them here, [http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/:](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/)

- [Mozilla Add-Ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/language-tools/)
- [LibreOffice](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/)
- [LibreOffice extensions](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center?getCategories=Dictionary&getCompatibility=any&sort_on=positive_ratings&path=%2FLibreOffice-Extensions-and-Templates%2Fextension-center&portal_type=PSCProject&SearchableText=)

The most of the sites listed were difficult to navigate and find any actual dictionaries. The Mozilla site was clean, easy to read and find the language I was looking for after I figured out how to download them so I'll describe how to get them from there.

To find and download the language files go to the Mozilla site, find the language you are looking for and click the, "Install Dictionary" link. 
[image]

It will load another page that has a, "Download" or "Add to Firefox" button. If it says, "Add to Firefox" right click on it and select "Save link as..." and it will open a save dialog. 
[image]

The file name will be something like, "german_dictionary_switzerland-2.0.4-fx+an+tb+sm.xpi". Download the file and then rename it to "german_dictionary_switzerland-2.0.4-fx+an+tb+sm.xpi.zip" since it is really just a zip file.

Unpack it and it should have at least the dictionary and rules file you need. They will be something like, "de_CH.aff" and "de_CH.dic". 
[image]

You can then copy these into the dictionary directory of your project

[image]

and add a language reference in the SpellingConfig file to use these with Squiggly:

```
  <LanguageResource language="German (Switzerland)" languageCode="de_CH" ruleFile="dictionaries/de_CH/de-CH.aff" dictionaryFile="dictionaries/de_CH/de-CH.dic"/>
```

Note that in Apache Flex version of Squiggly the config file is just named "SpellingConfig.xml" not "AdobeSpellingConfig.xml".

NOTE: The Mozilla site doesn't have all the dictionaries. I tried following the "Install Language Package" link and downloading that file but couldn't find the .aff or .dic files. I think that it's only a properties file for the browsers and not any type of dictionary files.

**UPDATE:**
If you have **Muse** installed you can find the open source libraries here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 0.3, **Squiggly** has moved to the **Hunspell** algorithm. 
Each **Hunspell** language dictionary is governed by its own open source license. As such, we advise you to read the licensing terms carefully before deciding to bundle any dictionary with your application. You will need to download your own dictionaries to get the most up-to-date content and for the other languages supported by this release (*English* (US), *French* (new in 0.6), *Spanish* (Spain), *Italian*, and *Portuguese* (Brazilian and Portugal)).

The most convenient locations for downloading Hunspell dictionaries are:

- http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/dictionary
- http://fmg-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html

The dictionaries are in their own file formats – **.oxt** and **.xpi**. While these extensions may appear to be proprietary, they are just zip files. Download the dictionary of your choice, rename them to ***.zip**, and extract the content to your local machine.

The two files Squiggly depends upon are the ***.dic*** file (word list) and the **.aff** file (language rules). While some dictionary bundles may contain other files, such as hyphenation pattern files or thesaurus files, those are not material to Squiggly. Copy the *.dic and *.aff files into your development project, and edit the **AdobeSpellingConfig.xml** file (found in [YourProject]/src/) to specify their location. A sample **AdobeSpellingConfig.xml** will look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <SpellingConfig>
  <LanguageResource 
    language="English" 
    languageCode="en_US" 
    ruleFile="src/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.aff" 
    dictionaryFile="src/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic"/>
 </SpellingConfig>
```

*The languageCode can be an arbitrary value, as long as you are consistent when passing them to the Squiggly classes. However, we highly encourage you to follow the two part Unicode language identifier format. For more information, please consult the latest Unicode Technical Standard that can be found at:* http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/